# Question about the expression 日和: Can it be used with any activity or just with certain set expressions?

Tags: words, usage, expressions

So I was watching a podcast for japanese learners and they gave 行楽日和、お散歩日和、お洗濯日和..as examples.

So now I am asking myself, can I attach 日和 only to certain things or to anything that fits the context?
Would for example 水泳日和 work to say like "great weather for swimming", or 自転車に乗ること日和 for "great weather to ride on a bike" or 花見日和. Would it work to use it like this?

Or to put the question simple: How exactly is 日和 used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, generally you can use whatever noun (or verbs in 連用形) that fits the context. But 自転車に乗ること日和 is too clumsy (verb-こと 日和 is too complex to fit in this form). Simply 自転車日和 is enough, or サイクリング日和．

The example you listed has actual usage:

- Everyone waits for お花見日和, so it's often mentioned in weather forecasts in spring. Weathernews: [午後もお花見日和続く](https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/202303/280105/).
- [水泳日和](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E6%B0%B4%E6%B3%B3%E6%97%A5%E5%92%8C%22) is often seen in school news.

Comment: なるほど。説明してくれたをありがとうございます。